# Create Declaration / Definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

With some IDE, once I declare a method in the `.h` file, it is possible to generate automatically the definition in the `.cpp` file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/refactoring/create-declaration-definition?view=msvc-160 It seems possible to do it as well with Visual Studio Code, but it looks outdated to me. I am not able to reproduce it.

How can I do it with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: VS Code is an extensible text editor that can be configured as an IDE.

Comment: your link is for Visual Studio, VS !== VSC

Comment: you can try: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this extension, works fine for me. You also can generete automatically `.h` files with `.cpp` ones. [c/c++ definition generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reignofwebber.c-cpp-definition-generator)